# How to match winning numbers to input numbers of users for lottery daoo?

Tags: solidity, dapps

I have tried to build lottery dapps and I feel hard to find first, second, third place winners.

For example,

5 matched number - first place winner

4 matched number - second place winner

3 matched number - third place winner

if the winning number is 12345,
The 4 matched number would be 192345
The 3 matched number would be 192545

I used to use mapping to find first winners, but considering second and third place winners, mapping seems not a good choice...

Could you please give me any advice or any helpful source codes ?

Comment: There's plenty of ways to go about this. Can you share your attempts so it's easier to spot what's wrong with them and guide you from there?

Comment: Thank you for your comment :) 
So, I made mapping to store participants' information,
let's say mapping(uint256 => mapping( uint256 => userinfo) userPickUpNumber.
which is mapping(round => mapping( selected number=> userinfo)
userInfo is struct ; address, how many times the number picked up.

then, 

when I execute announceWinner(uint256 winnerNumber) function,
This function has to do for-loop to gather all the winners (first, sencod, and thrid place)

Comment: but imagine that 
if there are many participants meaning that this function will use for loop a lot, it will be failed at some points because it could be out of gas...